# Не работает sql LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, sql

Имеется таблица футбольных клубов: [image]

Имеется таблица с датами игр этих футбольных клубов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется таблица связи для этих таблиц:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно чтобы в PHP выводились в массив хозяева поля, гости поля и даты игры.
Пробовал делать так, но не выводится ни хозяева, ни гости, ни дата.

```
<?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root'; 
    $pass = ''; 
    $name = 'mydb'; 

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);
    mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query = "SELECT
        games.football_club_master_id as master, football_club_guest_id as guest, date_id as date
    FROM
        games
    LEFT JOIN  football_clubs ON games.football_club_master_id = football_clubs.name
    LEFT JOIN  football_clubs as fc ON games.football_club_guest_id = fc.name
    LEFT JOIN  date_games ON games.date_id = date_games.date_game";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    for ($data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row);
    print_r($data);
```

?>

Comment: Так с чем проблема-то? с запросом? с его выполнением? с выводом результата?

Comment: Выводится такой массив:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [master] => 2 [guest] => 3 [date] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [master] => 3 [guest] => 2 [date] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [master] => 4 [guest] => 1 [date] => 5 ) [3] => Array ( [master] => 5 [guest] => 4 [date] => 4 ) )
А должно вместо цифр быть имена клубов и даты.

Answer (score 0):

Была ошибка в выборке имен, переписал переменyю $query:
$query = "SELECT
football_clubs.name as master, fc.name as guest, date_games.date_game as date
FROM
games
LEFT JOIN football_clubs ON games.football_club_master_id = football_clubs.id
LEFT JOIN football_clubs as fc ON games.football_club_guest_id = fc.id
LEFT JOIN date_games ON games.date_id = date_games.id";
Теперь работает.